# Google Cloud Functions: Function cannot be initialized. Error: function terminated

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm attempting to deploy my Cloud Function and receive the following error:

**Error:**
`Function cannot be initialized. Error: function terminated.`

**My code:**

```
const API_KEY = "";
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
var firebase = require('firebase')


firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

let database = firebase.database();

exports.callPSIApi = async (event, context) => {

  const message = event.data
    ? Buffer.from(event.data, 'base64').toString()
    : 'Hello, World';

  const apiCall = `https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?key=${API_KEY}&url=${message}&category=performance&strategy=mobile`;

  console.log(apiCall)
  const response = await fetch(apiCall)
  if (!response.ok) {
    const message2 = `An error has occurred: ${response.status}`;
    throw new Error(message2);
  }

  const data = await response.json();

  database.ref("customPath").set(data, function(error) {
    if (error) {
      // The write failed...
      console.log("Failed with error: " + error)
    } else {
      // The write was successful...
      console.log("success")
    }
})

  console.log("CALL PSI API FUNCTION RAN")
};
```

I need someone to look over my code and see if they see anything that's causing the error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please include the `package.json` in your question and how are you deploying your function? Have you already tried to put this in your console? `firebase functions:log`

Comment: I also posted an answer which you don't need to downgrade the Firebase version. Let me know if you have questions or clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade Firebase to fix the issue:

**Package.json:**

```
"firebase": "^8.10.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best to always use `firebase functions:log` to find out detailed error logs when deploying a function to Firebase.

Just to add. The posted answer is one of the workarounds but Firebase has the [**compat libraries**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#about_the_compat_libraries) which allows you to continue using version 8 code alongside code refactored for version 9. You don't need to downgrade from the latest version of Firebase to `^8.10.0`. You just need to change your imports. See sample code below:

```
var firebase = require('firebase/compat/app');
require('firebase/compat/database');
```

---

For more information, you may also check out this documentation:

- [Upgrade from version 8 to the modular Web SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade)